# How to make nodered opc ua server update its values?

Tags: iot, node-red, opc-ua, wincc

I am trying to use NodeRed OPC UA server on IOT2050 as a gateway between plc and SCADA.

I've set up communication to PLC from IOT2050 which gets me values and stores into set node variables.

Everything seems to works fine, I've checked with UaExpert, reading works and data updates just fine.

The problem is with WinCC it updates only when i read value via UaExpert i do not know why.

I use node-red-contrib-opcua-server to set up server and adress space.
Flow looks like this:

[image: Flow]

Script in Flow node looks like this:

[image: getset]

Everything is basically done as is shown in example for this node.

Am i missing something?

I am thinking that UaExpress does something which is not done by WinCC, but i don't know what exactly i need to do in order to update those variables. I've tried to use subscription but it doesnt seems to be doing anything. Should i try to read those variables to force update or is there any method to update all variables set in adress space of Complex Server, maybe by set interval?

I want WinCC to be able to read variables set in OPC UA server in set intervals.

Tried subscribing values but it doesn't seems to be doing anything.
UaExpress works fine, data is updated one i try to read them by it.

Checked WinCC connection, changed intervals for cycle acquisition but it did not help. It doesn't seems to be a problem from WinCC side, rather than from server side. No update cycle perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I've menaged to fix this by reading variables from node-red program which runs with OPC UA server.
Additional flow looks like this:
[image: flow]
It reads values of variables which causes them to update on server.
WinCC visualisation updates as fast as additional flow reads(updates) values.

I haven't figured out how to triger updating from WinCC side, so it is the only solution for my problem i came up with for now.